# Adversarial input for this regex

Tags: python, regex, performance, security, non-greedy

Someone asked me an interview question: write a function `match(s, t)` to decide if a string `s` is a *generalized substring* of another string `t`. More concretely, `match` should return True if and only if removing some characters in `t` can equalize it to `s`. For example, `match("abc", "abbbc")` is True, because we can remove the two extra `b`s in `t`.

Surely the interviewer is expecting some kind of recursive solution, but I'm feeling adventurous and wrote

```
def match(s, t):
    return re.search('.*?'.join(s), t) is not None
```

This seems to satisfy all the test cases, but then I started wondering if there exists any adversarial input that can hog this operation (and potentially make our service vulnerable to DoS attacks). See [this great article](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html) for an extended discussion, but as a quick example, try

```
re.match("a?"*29+"a"*29, "a"*29)
```

and it will take several seconds before finding a match. The reason is that `re` implements a backtracking regex engine:

> Consider the regular expression a?<sup>n</sup>a<sup>n</sup>. It matches the string a<sup>n</sup> when the a? are chosen not to match any letters, leaving the entire string to be matched by the a<sup>n</sup>. Backtracking regular expression implementations implement the zero-or-one ? by first trying one and then zero. There are n such choices to make, a total of 2<sup>n</sup> possibilities. Only the very last possibility—choosing zero for all the ?—will lead to a match. The backtracking approach thus requires O(2<sup>n</sup>) time, so it will not scale much beyond n=25.

Back to the interview question, technically `'.*?'.join(s)` gives us at least `len(s) - 1` choices to make, which means there can be some adversarial inputs similar to the `"a?"*29+"a"*29` and `"a"*29` above, but I failed to find them after some trial and error.

Question: what `s` and `t` can make `match` ridiculously slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy quantifiers are generally quite good for performance, but AFAIK they do not prevent the pathological emphasized behaviour.

This is especially true when the beginning of the regexp match with the beginning of a text but the match is early and will fail at the end of the text requiring a lot of backtracks to "fix" the bad early lazy match of the beginning of the regexp.

In your case, here is an example of pathological input requiring an exponential number of steps:

```py
# This should take at least few minutes to compute
n = 12
match('ab'*(n+1), 'abbbbb'*n+'a')
```

Here is the number of steps and the Python `match` time required based on the value of `n`:

```
 n |  steps |    time
 1 |     44 |   2.4 µs
 2 |    374 |   6.4 µs
 3 |   2621 |  22.1 µs
 4 |  18353 | 131.3 µs
 5 | 126211 | 925.8 µs
 6 |    -   |   6.2 ms
 7 |    -   |  42.2 ms
 8 |    -   | 288.7 ms
 9 |    -   |  1.97 s
```

You can understand and analyse the resulting regexp matching behaviour on [this great website](https://regex101.com/) (more specifically backtracking in this case).

Comment: I wonder what `.*?` tries first, consuming the next character or not? I can tell from your example that it attempts matching as much as possible before backtracking, but according to [the document for `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), non-greedy qualifiers means "as few characters as possible will be matched".

Comment: If `.*?` tries matching as many characters as possible before backtracking, then `s = t = 'a'*n` should also be a pathological input (because it would eventually run out of characters in `t` by consuming too much early on), but a quick experiment shows it isn't :/

Comment: `.*?` is lazy and thus try to match the first characters as much as possible, but this strategy is not always the good one (like here for example). The sentence "as few characters as possible will be matched" is respected here for each `.*?` : the length of the matched string by `.*?` is minimized. However, the regex has to find a valid match and because of the first worst matching choice of the first `.*?` (due to the lazy quantifier), a lot of backtracks are needed.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow: if `.*?` "try to match the first characters as much as possible", then why does `re.match('a(.*?)', 'aaa').group(1)` give an empty string? If it tries to match greedily before backtracking, then I should get `'aa'` as the first (and only) capture group.

Comment: `s = t = 'a'*n` is not a problem. Indeed, the first `.*?` will start by not matching anything (because of the lazy quantifier), then `a` is matched, then the second `.*?` do the same, and in the end, all character will be matched without backtracking. `.*?a` behave a bit like `[^a]*+a` until the remaining part of the regexp fails.

Comment: Sorry, I think my sentence was ambiguous. I was thinking about the next character following the `.*?` when I wrote it. So for example the regexp `.*?a` will search for the first `a` in the matched string (from the current matching location). The `.*?` will not match a string with any `a` in the beginning. When the regexp engine needs to backtrack, then is can match the `a`.  `re.match('a(.*?)', 'aaa').group(1)` will match the first `a` and then the `.*?` will match nothing because `a` is already a valid match. `re.match` do not need to match the whole input (unless `^$` characters are used).

Comment: Thus to be more accurate, let say the engine "try to find the first characters in the searched text from the current location matching with the regexp pattern following `.*?`". If this is not more clear for you, then you can just keep in mind that `.*?` try to minimize the length of the matched string (for this part of the regexp) while `.*+` try to maximize the length of the matched string. Is it more clear?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Please allow me to ask for one more clarification: why does `match('ab'*(n+1), 'abbbbb'*n+'a')` cause so many backtracks? In other words, when/where exactly do the backtracks happen? I know it's a pathological input, but couldn't understand its behavior

Comment: It causes so many backtrack because of both the many `b` between each `a` and the fact that there is no possible valid matching string (causing a brute-force). Indeed, the engine first tries to match the whole string then then see that there is a missing needed `a` in the end. Then, it tries to backtrack so that previous partial match of `.*?` can change the outcomes, but this is not possible. There is something like 5 possible backtracks, so 6 tries (I am not sure about this number) for each possible group of `b`. Thus, at least `6*6*...*6 = O(6^n)` steps.

Comment: I strongly advise you to check the most critical case on [this website](https://regex101.com/) (you can see how the engine parses the string by clicking on the "catastrophic backtracking" button). You can see how the engine starts to parse the whole string and then backtrack 5 times for the last group and then backtrack one time for the previous group and then 5 times again for the last group (stupidly as nothing will change), and so on so forth.

Comment: I see. Didn't realize regex101 has a "catastrophic backtracking" button! However, I want to point out that `match('ab'*(n+1), 'abbbbb'*n)` (without the trailing 'a') is also a pathological input, and in this case there is a valid matching string!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution suffers due to backtracking, which is why the accepted answer was able to provide inputs that will slow it down considerably.

Here is a regex solution which closely mimics my previous answer, and it also seems to avoid the issues plaguing your current solution.

```
def match(s, t):
    return re.search("".join(f'[^{re.escape(c)}]*{re.escape(c)}' for c in s), t) is not None
```

---

### Previous answer

This doesn't directly answer your question, but

> Surely the interviewer is expecting some kind of recursive solution...

I don't think so. Something like this can also work

```
def match(s, t):
    i = -1
    return all ((i := t.find(c, i + 1)) != -1 for c in s)
```

I just wanted to provide an alternative solution that doesn't require recursion or regex and therefore leading to the vulnerabilities you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. If I wasn't so adventurous I would write a tail-recursive solution (by dispatching on the very first character of `s` and `t`, if there is one), which should also dodge the bullet as you do :P

Comment: @nalzok I added a regex solution as well, which also bypasses the possibility of making the search painfully slow